# keep audio pitch constant in javafx video player on changing speed

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I have developed a video player using **javafx** but when I increase the rate of the player i.e the speed of the player using **mediaPlayer.setRate(1.5)** method, the speed of the video is increased, but the audio sounds like a **chipmunk**.

I need to implement functionality like with youtube where if we increase the speed, it doesn't sound like a chipmunk.

Please help me - what can I do to achieve this?
What java api, class or 3rd party library should I use in my program in order to modify the audio pitch whilst running the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution 
Use VLCJ : http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj 
VLCJ is a java wrapper framework that uses native vlc libraries.
They have very nice documentation and examples on Github.
It also supports JavaFx. 
Github link : 
VlcJ : https://github.com/caprica 
VlcJ - JavaFx : https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx